# Performance hit by using Spring jdbcTemplate compared to plain PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbctemplate

i am just benchmarking a complex system and found that queries going through Spring are really slow.

It adds ~600ms.

The benchmark code compares the following:

```
case TEMPLATE:
{
    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    jdbcTemplate.update(getUnnamedPreparedStatement(query), new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            int i = 1;
            for (Object o : queryParameters) {
                ps.setObject(i++, o);
            }
        }
    });
    break;
}

case PREPAREDSTATEMENT:
{
    Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();
    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(getUnnamedPreparedStatement(query));
    int index = 1;
    for (Object parameter: queryParameters) {
        ps.setObject(index++, parameter);
    }
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    break;
}
```

Both queries give the same result and the order does not matter.
Moreover, it does not depend on the query type (i.e. SELECT, UPDATE).

I have run the test a dozen times and the results are stable.

What does the Spring jdbcTemplate do, that the PreparedStatement does not do?

Comment: Just a note: in your prepared statement scenario, you are not including the time taken to get a connection. Depending on your configuration, it's not safe to assume that this operation is trivial or of inconsequential time consumption.

Comment: pap thanks for your answer. However, getting the connection takes arround 20ms in my setup. And I assume that the jdbcTemplate reuses existing connections and does not aquire new ones on every `update`

Comment: @Felix, reusing connections has nothing to do with spring but with your connection pool if you have it.  So that should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment above seems to be the correct answer I'll post it as an answer for future consulting.

*@Felix, reusing connections has nothing to do with spring but with your connection pool if you have it. So that should be taken into account.*

So basicly I think the connection pool was missing in the spring project.

Answer (score 0):

Your first case executes an update query, whereas the second one executes a select query. The second one should use `ps.executeUpdate()` to be similar to the first one.